# Add strings to MFC ComboBox

Tags: c++, visual-c++, combobox, mfc

Trying to add strings to ComboBox:

```
BOOL CMyAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    CComboBox *combo= (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_TT);
    combo->AddString("s1");
    combo->AddString("s2");

    // ...
    return TRUE;
}
```

Why ComboBox list is still empty?

Comment: No idea. You failed to check the return value of the `AddString` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the first string if you call combo->SetCurSel(0)?  If so it means the combo box drop down size is zero. In the visual dialog editor click on the combo's down arrow then drag the bottom edge down to resize the drop down part.